# Removing Duplicate Words Across Multiple and Large Dictionary Files

Tags: algorithm, sorting, memory-management, gpu, dictionary

I have roughly ~600GB of dictionaries I've accumulated over the years, and I decided I want to clean them up and sort them

First of all, each file on average is very large, anywhere from 500MB to 9GB in size. A prerequisite for what I want to do is that I sort each dictionary. My end goal is to entirely remove duplicate words *within* and *throughout* **all** dictionary files.

The reason for this is that most of my dictionaries are sorted and organized by categories, but duplicates still often exist.

```
Load file
     Read each line and put into data structure
     Sort and remove any and all duplicate
Load next file and repeat

Once all files are individually unique, compare against eachother and remove duplicates
```

**For Dictionaries D{1} to D{N}:**

1) Sort *D{1}* through *D{N}* individually.

2) Check uniqueness of each word in *D{i}*

3) For each word in *D{i}*, check ALL words across *D{i+1}* to *D{N}*. Delete each word if unique in *D{i}* first.

- I am considering using a sort of "hash" to improve this algorithm. Possibly by only checking the first one or two characters, since the list will be sorted (e.g. hash beginning line location for words starting with a, b, etc.).

4) Save and exit.

Example before (but far smaller):

```
    Dictionary 1            Dictionary 2            Dictionary 3

    ]a                      0u3TGNdB                2 KLOCK
    all                     avisskriveri            4BZ32nKEMiqEaT7z
    ast                     chorion                 4BZ5
    astn                    chowders                bebotch
    apiala                  chroma                  bebotch
    apiales                 louts                   bebotch
    avisskriveri            lowlander               chorion
    avisskriverier          namely                  PC-Based
    avisskriverierne        silking                 PC-Based
    avisskriving            underwater              PC-Based
```

So it would see avisskriveri, chorion, bebotch and PC-Based are words that repeate both within and among each of the three dictionaries. So I see avisskriveri in *D{1}* first, so remove it in all other instances that I have seen it in. Then I see chorion in *D{2}* first, and remove that in all other instances first, and so forth. In *D{3}* bebotch and PC-Based are replicated, so I want to delete all but one entry of it (unless I've seen it before). Then save all files and close.

Example after:

```
     Dictionary 1           Dictionary 2            Dictionary 3

     ]a                     0u3TGNdB                2 KLOCK
     all                    chorion                 4BZ32nKEMiqEaT7z
     ast                    chowders                4BZ5
     astn                   chroma                  bebotch
     apiala                 louts                   PC-Based
     apiales                lowlander                   
     avisskriveri           namely              
     avisskriverier         silking                 
     avisskriverierne       underwater                          
     avisskriving
```

**Remember:** I do NOT want to create any new dictionaries, only remove duplicates across all dictionaries.

**Options:**

- "Hash" the amount of unique words for each file, allowing the program to estimate the computation time.
- Specify a way give the location of the first word beginning with the desired first letter. So that the search may "jump" to a line and skip unecessary computational time.
- Run on GPU for high performance parallel computing. (This is an issue because getting the data off of the GPU is tricky)

**Goal:** Reduce computational time and space consumption so that the method is affordable on a standard machine or server with limited abilities. Or device a method for running it remotely on a GPU cluster.

tl;dr - Sorting unique words across hundreds of files, where each file is 1-9GB in size.

Comment: I don't have a full solution, but perhaps a [trie map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) will help for efficiently storing your list of words in memory without duplicates. eg. Each leaf of the node contains a true/false depending on whether that path is a valid dictionary word.

Comment: Do you must eliminate duplicates at runtime or can you work on the files before (one time), where tools unix like `sort` and `uniq` could be of great help on huge files ?

Comment: What format are the files? Are they simple text files, one word per line? Are their contents sorted?

Comment: What java and c++ tags to do with your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ, the files are mostly .txt, .lst and .dic files. Essentially all can easily be loaded. The contents are mostly sorted among each individual file.

Comment: @NeonGlow, I have experience in both, and I would prefer either Java or C++ to write an application to do this kind of sorting among files. So I am open to suggestions in either language.

Comment: @Alex, I would be doing some sorting among the files yes. I haven't tried doing anything in bash yet. Do you think sort or uniq would be useful across multiple files?

Comment: @Signus if the files are sorted, my solution will solve your problem with minimal memory usage. The only drawback is that you have to have about 100 files open at any given time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14619756/582136

Comment: Could you provide an example, how they are looking (the files and words)? Especially how long are the words and which characters can occur?

Comment: As I mentioned the files are a word-per-line dictionary a piece. Each file has anywhere from a million to hundreds of millions or more words. So they are 1-3GB average in size. And they are mostly alphanumeric, special characters and all anywhere from 1 to 18 characters. 

I like my dictionaries big. ^_^

Comment: @Signus Check this out http://code.google.com/p/externalsortinginjava/

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    typedef std::set<string> Words;
    Words words;
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word)
        words.insert(word);  // will only work if not seen before
    for (Words::const_iterator i = words.begin(); i != words.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i;
}
```

Then just:

```
cat file1 file2... | ./this_wonderful_program > greatest_dictionary.txt
```

Should be fine assuming the number of non-duplicate words fits in memory (likely on any modern PC, especially if you've 64 bits and > 4GB), this will probably be I/O bound anyway so no point fussing over unordered map vs (binary-tree) map etc..  You may want to convert to lower-case, strip spurious characters etc. before inserting to the map.

EDIT:

If the unique words don't fit in memory, or you're just stubbornly determined to sort each individual input then merge them, you can use the unix `sort` command on each file, then `sort -m` to efficiently merge the pre-sorted files.  If you're not on UNIX/Linux, you can probably still find a port of `sort` (e.g. from Cygwin for Windows), your OS may have an equivalent program, or you could try compiling the `sort` source code.  Note that this approach is a little different from tb-'s suggestion of asking one invocation of `sort` to sort everything (presumably in memory) - I'm not sure how well that would work, so best to try/compare.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll give something like this a shot.. However I really would prefer to sort each dictionary file of unique words and save those, and then compare along each dictionary file. This being because I have >300GB of dictionaries.

Comment: @Signus: The above will be massively faster if the set of *unique* words can fit in RAM, *especially* when the total size of dictionary inputs is huge - the speed is O(Nlog2U) where N is the total number of words and U is the number of unique words.  That's good!  You can try an unordered map for O(N), but may not notice the difference as log2U will probably settle to a value around 20+/-2, and hashing can be slow anyway.  Having to sort each separate input dictionary in O(Nlog2N) then merge is unlikely to help given the dictionaries are individually pretty chunky.

Comment: It would be time consuming either way. As far as memory goes, I have plenty of RAM to load at least a few dictionaries at a time into memory, however this is not true for all people.

O(Nlog2U) would be pretty good time, even considering the trillions and trillions of words I have. Sorting each dictionary alone of unique words would not be so much a problem, it's the comparison of each dictionary to each other dictionary that is a problem.

Comment: @Signus: respectfully, I don't think your conception of what's a problem is well founded - please try it then tell us how it goes....

Comment: I understand the algorithm and could easily write a crude solution to removing duplicates among each individual file. Devising a method for comparing words across dictionaries would very much be a problem. Seeing as I would come upon "word" in Dictionary 1, then I would search M entries across Dictionaries 1...N, where M is the amount of words in D{i}. 

Also look at some of the edits I made to try and further describe what I would like to do. I greatly appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1):

On that that scale of 300GB+, you may want to consider using [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) or some other scalable store - otherwise, you will have to deal with memory issues through your own coding.  You can try other, more direct methods (UNIX scripting, small C/C++ programs, etc...), but you will likely run out of memory unless you have a ton of duplicate words in your data.

**Addendum**

Just came across [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) which seems very close to what you are trying to accomplish: but you may have to tweak it **not** to throw away the oldest values.  I don't have time to check right now, but you should do a search on **[Distributed Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_tables)**.

Comment: Yep, this approach is safest and more preferable.

Comment: I'll look into Hadoop and see if it will be useful for my application.  My problem is that many of my dictionaries are multi-million or multi-billion worded, therefore just removing duplicates within a single dictionary is complex enough.

Comment: @Signus you hit the nail on the head: I suspected that part of your solution will involve a distributed dictionary (eg segment A-G in one file/machine, H-N for the next file/machine, etc...).  If you can find a package that already has this functionality built-in, you will be half-way there.  Also look into anything related to MapReduce: I'm certain Google does not keep a single large hash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dictionaries are in alphabetical order and line by line, one word per line (as are most dictionaries), you could do something like this:

```
Open a file stream to each file.
Open a file stream to the compiled list file.
Read 1 entry from each file and put it onto a heap, priority queue, or other sorted data structure.
while you still have entries
    find & remove the first entry, storing the word (it is not necessary to store the file)
    read in the next entry from that file, if one exists
    find & remove any duplicates of the stored entry
    read in the next entry for each of those files, if one exists
    write the stored word to your compiled list file
Close all of the streams
```

The efficiency of this is something like O(n*m*log(n)) and the space efficiency is O(n), where n is the number of files and m is the average number of entries.

Note that you'll want to create a data type that pairs entries (strings) with file pointers/references, and sorts by string storing. You'll also need a data structure that allows you to peek before you pop.

If you have questions in implementation, ask me.

A more thorough analysis of the efficiency:

Space efficiency is pretty easy. You fill the data structure, and for every item you put on, you take one off, so it stays at O(n).

Computational efficiency is more complex. The looping itself is O(n*m), because you will consider each entry, and there are n*m entries. Some c percent of those will be valid, but that's a constant, so we don't care.

Next, adding and removing from a priority queue is log(n) both ways, so to find & remove is 2*log(n).

Because we add and remove each entry, we get n*m add and removes, so O(n*m*log(n)). I think it might actually be a theta in this case, but meh.

Comment: I will see where I can go with this approach. Given that I make sure they are all sorted (may include that in some functionality). However I will have to modify your method when I compare across files (because I don't want to create one mega-list).

Comment: @Signus Do you mean one mega list in memory? If you apply this correctly, the list will at most contain a number of elements equal to the number of files. If you have 300 files, that's 300 elements.

Comment: Well I don't want to create one list in either memory or a single file because of the sheer size of everything.

Comment: @Signus I'm not quite sure what you mean. As I understand, you want to create a new dictionary that is a combination off all of the other dictionaries without repeats, yes? I don't think you can get any more space efficient than O(n) without the use of `seek()`, because you will have to consider every dictionary when determining where the next word will come from.

Comment: I am sorry that I'm not being entirely clear. I'm adding edits as I go to make sure people understand what it is I am trying to do. First off, I do NOT want to create a new dictionary, I want to edit my existing dictionaries by removing the duplicate words between each individual file AND all of the dictionaries. This way I have nothing but unique words across ALL of my dictionaries. This is   why I'm trying to look for an efficient method for loading very large files and comparing them to other very large files. Sorting each dictionary alone isn't a problem.

Comment: I decided I may go through this process by creating a single dictionary that gets split into 500-1500MB files as it writes. That way it is more manageable to read/write to and it isn't a task to load each file without using vim/nano/emacs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, there is no pattern to exploit in a clever way. So we want to do raw sorting.

Let us assume that no cluster farm is available (we could do other things then)

Then I would start with the easiest approach possible, the command line tool `sort`:

> sort -u inp1 inp2 -o sorted

This will sort `inp1` and `inp2` together in output file `sorted` without duplicates (u = unique). Sort typically uses a customized mergesort algorithm, which can handle a limited amount of memory. So you should not run in memory problems.
You should have at least 600 gb (double the size) of free disk space.
You should test with only 2 input files how long it takes and what happens. My tests did not show any problems, but they had used different data and an afs server (which is rather slow, but is a better emulation as some HPC filesystem provider):

```
$ ll
2147483646 big1
2147483646 big2

$ time sort -u big1 big2 -o bigsorted
1009.674u 6.290s 28:01.63 60.4% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w

$ ll
2147483646 big1
2147483646 big2
 117440512 bigsorted
```